# openssl suppress progress display

Tags: linux, openssl

When generating a private key, OpenSSL prints progress dots to the console as dots.  In my automated build pipeline, this results in a single dot being printed on each line, which clutters up the display.  Is there an option to suppress this progress display?  I know I could redirect the output with `2>/dev/null` but I don't want to hide everything.  Example command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=localhost" -keyout ./localhost.key -out ./localhost.crt
```